# How do I subtract the values of a 1x2 matrix from a 2 x 2 matrix in octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm brand new to Octave, and I'm trying to do some basic matrix operations. I'll give a simple example of what I'm trying to do (actual data set is much larger).

```
a = [1 2; 2 4]
mu = mean(a)
normalized = a - mu %error line
```

So in my example, the mu values are 1.5 and 6. I'd like to get a matrix back that has 1.5 subtracted from the first column, and 3 subtracted from the 2nd.

Such as:

-.5  -1
 .5   1

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normalized = a - repmat(mu, size(a,1), 1)`

Comment: Thanks Ben. Looking at repmat function now.

Answer (score 3):

In Maltab (and it will work in Octave too) you would do it using a [binary singelton expansion](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@minus, a, mu)
```

However, my understanding is that Octave does [broadcasting](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) automatically for you and so you shouldn't get an error trying to subtract a 1x2 matrix from a 2x2... :/

Comment: automatic broadcasting was added recently in 3.6: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.6.html

Answer (score 1):

```
normalized  = [a(:,1) - mu(1), a(:,2) - mu(2)];
```